# Can webdriver get the style sheet url that is being used by an element

Tags: javascript, c#, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a test case in which I need to verify that changing an option in a drop down list changes the styling the page. I am wondering if Webdriver is capable of getting the css document url from an element. I feel as this is the best solution for my test case as I do now know what will change on the page but I do know it will have a different css source from the original page load. Attached is a screenshot of the information I am hoping to extract. Maybe possible with `getCssValue()` but I am not sure what css property that would be if any. [image]

Answer (score -1):

```
<input id="username" name="name" value="selenium">input</input>
```

You can user `element.getAttirbute("");` , in this case if you use `driver.findElement(By.Id('username')).getAttribute("value");` It will return selenium.